# Bitbake: modify a bbappend depending on the image compiled

Tags: bitbake, recipe, openembedded

I have two different images which use a lot of common packages. One of them is the wpa-supplicant, which provides a file `wpa_supplicant.conf` installed by the default recipe. However, I want my own `wpa_supplicant.conf` to be installed.

I have this solved by having a `.bbappend` in my layer. But now I only want this append to be applied when I compile one of the images, but not the other.

In short: is there a way to enable/disable a `.bbappend` depending on the image compiled?

**NOTES:**

- I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33296770/2283531) which is similar, but creating a new package that install my file does not work: many packages will try to install the same file and Bitbake returns error.

  - The error here is that I cannot install the same file from two different packages, that's why this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288622/using-bitbake-is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-do-install-for-a-package-based) IMO.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bitbake is it possible to have a different do\_install for a package based on the target image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288622/using-bitbake-is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-do-install-for-a-package-based)

Comment: @Anders I reference that question in my answer. It is similar, but the fundamental problem I am having is different (cannot have two packages installing the same file), that's why I ask about the .bbappend possibility.

Comment: Well, the question was the same, ie a single machine. His own answer is different, as he used two machines.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just as is stated in the answer that you link to, you can't have the image influence any other recipe. The reason is that each recipe is built indepent of which image you're building.

Are the different images intended to be installed onto the same `MACHINE`? Otherwise you could have different `wpa_supplicant.conf` for each `MACHINE`.

For the same `MACHINE`:

- Using `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` is one way to solve this
- Add both `wpa_supplicant.conf`-files (with differing names) andadd a `pkg_post_inst_${PN}(){xxx}` script to your `wpa-supplicant`, that during rootfs-creation time, detects which image is being built, and selects the corretct `wpa_supplicant.conf`.
- Another solution is remove `wpa_supplicant.conf` from the `wpa-supplicant` package in your bbappend. Create two new packages `wpa-supplicant-conf1` and `wpa-supplicant-conf2`, which just includes the respective `wpa_supplicant.conf`. Those two should ideally have a

`wpa-supplicant-conf1`:

```
RCONFLICTS_${PN} = "wpa-supplicant-conf2"
```

and for `wpa-supplicant-conf2`

```
RCONFLICTS_${PN} = "wpa-supplicant-conf1"
```

in their recipes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the machine type is the same, physically there will be two different boards. I will investigate those further because I am not familiar with `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` neither with `pkg_post_inst_${PN}`.

Regarding the third solution: how do I remove a file with a `.bbappend`? Removing it with `do_install_append()?`

Comment: Yes, an `rm` inside a `do_install_append()` works perfectly well.

Comment: It's ok to create different, identical machines or distros for different configurations. For example, in early testing we used our vendor's DISTRO and MACHINE, but as we refined our own image, we created new MACHINE and DISTRO configurations that `include`d the vendor configs and changed them to be how we wanted to run.