# Yocto - select the right configuration file based on image type

Tags: yocto

In my pretty standard Yocto build I have the `openssh` included. Its configuration file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, should naturally be different for production and development images (for example one would like root login on development image and not on production one).
The production and the development images are different recipes (.bb files) in `recipes-core/images` under my layer, which includes some other stuff as well.
In order to achieve customization for the `sshd_config` file, I've created `recipes-connectivity/openssh` directory under my layer with `openssh_%.bbappend` with just the following content:

```
SUMMARY = "OpenSSH configuration"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

And in the `files` directory, I've got my own `sshd_conf`. This works fine, my file is used instead of openssh's default one. But how can I have, say, two separate files that will affect the two different resulting rootfs's?
The closest I've seen is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265618/yocto-install-different-config-files-based-on-machine-type-or-target-image), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281083/2702736) seems just too simple to be true. I've tried using my image names for folders, but all I got is the default conf file in both resulting image builds. The second answer seams reasonable, but AFAIK I can't replace a file coming from other recipe (please correct me if I'm wrong), so probably that was quite a specific case for the OP that worked.
Running a post-install script is not an option, since the rootfs is read-only on the target.
Studying the _append_xxxx stuff in the manual did not push me to the right direction as well.

Hope someone could share some experience on that, as this seems a pretty straightforward issue that should have some built-in solution.

Thanks.

Comment: May be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295803/bitbake-modify-a-bbappend-depending-on-the-image-compiled

Comment: One solution is to use [overlay bbclass](https://github.com/nefethael/meta-random/blob/master/classes/image_overlay.bbclass). Another solution is to create a custom variable in local.conf, let say `IS_PROD = "1"`, then you can use something like this in your image recipe: `SRC_URI += "${@ "file://conf1" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('IS_PROD')) else "file://conf2" }"`

Comment: @Nayfe, I don't want to have this set in local.conf, as it is the same file for both images. @danlor, maybe I can use two separate recipes that add a `pkg_postinst_${PN}() {}` which replaces the file, and add them in the different image recipes? Will try that. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you can do quite the same thing in `do_install()` to rename conf1 or conf2 in `sshd_config`. You can also tweak a default file with `echo/sed` in a `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the kind help I've received so far and several other answers, I've reached a working solution.

In my layer there's the `recipes-connectivity/openssh/openssh_%.bbappend`  with the following contents:

```
do_install_append () {
    rm ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssh/sshd_config
}
```

This removes the `sshd_config` file installed by the original `openssh` recipe.

Next, there are two additional recipes in my layer: `recipes-core/openssh_conf_prod/openssh_conf_dev_0.1.bb` and `recipes-core/openssh_conf_prod/openssh_conf_prod_0.1.bb`. In both recipe directories under `files` subdirectory there's an `opensshd_conf` file, different for `dev` and `prod`. The `.bb` recipes **are identical** for both cases, though:

```
DEPENDS = "openssh"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/meta/COPYING.MIT;md5=3da9cfbcb788c80a0384361b4de20420"

SRC_URI = "file://sshd_config"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssh
    install ${WORKDIR}/sshd_config ${D}${sysconfdir}/ssh
}
```

(*) Note the `DEPENDS` in the beginning.

What the recipe does is just verifies there's a destination directory to copy the file to, and copies the file it has under the `files` directory to the target rootfs.

Then, of course, the `prod` and `dev` image files under my recipe's `recipes-core/images` directory include each the relevant `openssh_conf_dev` or `openssh_conf_prod` recipes under, for example, the `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL_append` variable.

To conclude, the flow is:

1. `openssh` is being installed as required by the image recipe.
2. The `sshd_config` is being deleted by the new `.bbappend` recipe for `openssh`.
3. Each type of image calls its own recipe, which adds the right configuration file to the right folder.

I am not sure how elegant this is, but it does the job.