# Yocto How to overwrite a file of linux rootfs depending on an IMAGE-recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to add a simple line in *fstab* within
the final rootfs that Yocto builds.

My first approach was to add my own *fstab* in my layer **meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/fstab** and the proper **meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/base-files_%.bbappend** which only have the following line:

> FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

And it works, but as the title of my question says, i want to modify *fstab* based on the recipe-image i want to build i.e. **dev-image** & **prod-image**.

After some investigation i think i have 2 options

1. Modify *fstab* within the recipe image, extending the do_install task...

```
dev-image.bb
--------------

DESCRIPTION = "Development Image"
[...]
inherit core-image

do_install_append () {
    echo "=======  Modifying fstab ========"
    cat >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab <<EOF

# The line i want to Add

EOF
}
[...]

--------------
```

**Problem is** that i'm actually not seeing my modified line in my final /etc/fstab and bitbake is not showing any build error or warning about this, actually, i'm not even able to see the echo-trace i put.

2. My second attempt was to handle these modifications with packages and depending on the recipe-image i will be able to add the package for *-dev or *-prod. This idea was taken from *Oleksandr Poznyak* in [this answer](https://narkive.com/XcannnRd:3.603.68) in summary he suggest the following:

> 1) Create *.bbappend recipe base-files_%s.bbappend in your layer. It
>   appends to poky "base-files" recipe.
>
> 2) Create your own "python do_package_prepend" function where you should
>   make your recipe produce two different packages
>
> 3) Add them to DEPENDS in your image recipe

And based on his [example](https://narkive.com/XcannnRd:5.342.59) i made my own recipe:

```
base-files_%.bbappend
-------------------------
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://fstab-dev \                                                   
file://fstab-prod \
"

PACKAGES += " ${PN}-dev ${PN}-prod"
CONFFILES_${PN}-dev = "${CONFFILES_${PN}}"
CONFFILES_${PN}-prod = "${CONFFILES_${PN}}"

pkg_preinst_${PN}-dev = "${pkg_preinst_${PN}}"
pkg_preinst_${PN}-prod = "${pkg_preinst_${PN}}"

RREPLACES_${PN}-dev = "${PN}"
RPROVIDES_${PN}-dev = "${PN}"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-dev = "${PN}"

RREPLACES_${PN}-prod = "${PN}"
RPROVIDES_${PN}-prod = "${PN}"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-prod = "${PN}"

python populate_packages_prepend() {
    import shutil

    packages = ("${PN}-dev", "${PN}-prod")
    for package in packages:
    # copy ${PN} content to packages
        shutil.copytree("${PKGD}", "${PKGDEST}/%s" % package, symlinks=True)
    # replace fstab
    if package == "${PN}-dev":
        shutil.copy("${WORKDIR}/fstab-dev", "${PKGDEST}/${PN}-dev/etc/fstab")
    else:
        shutil.copy("${WORKDIR}/fstab-prod", "${PKGDEST}/${PN}-prod/etc/fstab")
}
-------------------------
```

And in my recipe-image(dev-image.bb) i added base-files-dev packet

```
dev-image.bb
--------------

DESCRIPTION = "Development Image"
[...]
inherit core-image

IMAGE_INSTALL = " \
 ${MY_PACKETS} \
 base-files-dev \
"

[...]

--------------
```

**Problem with this**, is that i'm not familiarized with phyton indentation so probably i'm messing things up, the error log shows as follows.

```
DEBUG: Executing python function populate_packages
ERROR: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:populate_packages(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/build/share/build_2/../sources/poky/meta/classes/package.bbclass', lineno: 1138, function: populate_packages
     1134:
     1135:    workdir = d.getVar('WORKDIR')
     1136:    outdir = d.getVar('DEPLOY_DIR')
     1137:    dvar = d.getVar('PKGD')
 *** 1138:    packages = d.getVar('PACKAGES').split()
     1139:    pn = d.getVar('PN')
     1140:
     1141:    bb.utils.mkdirhier(outdir)
     1142:    os.chdir(dvar)
File: '/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py', lineno: 315, function: copytree
     0311:    destination path as arguments. By default, copy2() is used, but any
     0312:    function that supports the same signature (like copy()) can be used.
     0313:
     0314:    """
 *** 0315:    names = os.listdir(src)
     0316:    if ignore is not None:
     0317:        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
     0318:    else:
     0319:        ignored_names = set()
Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '${PKGD}'

DEBUG: Python function populate_packages finished
DEBUG: Python function do_package finished
```

I will really appreciate any clue or sort of direction, i'm not an Yocto expert so maybe the options that i suggest are not the most elegant and probably there is a better way to do it, so be free to give me any recommendation.

Thank you very much.

### UPDATE:

As always, i was not the only one trying this, the way that i make it work was thanks this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584687/8033671) the only inconvenience with this is that you need to rm what you want to install through a .bbappend but for now is fine for me.

I also tried to do the same with bbclasses, which for me, it is a more  [elegant way](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-June/041378.html)to do it, but i failed... i got the following error

> ERROR: base-files-dev-3.0.14-r89 do_packagedata: The recipe base-files-dev is trying to install files into a shared area when those files already exist. Those files and their manifest location are:

I tried to rm fstab within the .bbappend but the same error is showed

Maybe somebody will share what i'm doing wrong...

If you don't find this post valuable please remove...

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe which base on Oleksandr doesn't work due to dropped support for variables expansion in newer Poky.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-2.1-variable-expansion-in-python-functions

Error explicit says: 
Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '${PKGD}'
It didn't expand the variable.

P.S.

This is not a proper answer to Your question but SO blocks comments.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a small modification in fstab you can also use ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND:append in your dev-image & prod-image .bbappend files.
Here is my bbappend where i delete some lines from interfaces file.

```
remove_wlan0_setup() {
    sed -i '7,13d' ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/network/interfaces
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND:append = " remove_wlan0_setup; "
```